# Traffic control plugin for Squid Cache

Tags: proxy, squid

Is there any traffic control plugin for Squid Cache? One that allows me to check if that specific user has consumed X amount of MBs or similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use a monitoring service to monitor your Squid Proxy. Something like [Sqstat](http://samm.kiev.ua/sqstat/) would help you to monitor the traffic per user. Alternately, you could also try [Squidview](http://freecode.com/projects/squidview) which has searching and reporting functions or something called [squint](http://www.dataparadis.net/osp/gnu-linux-server/proxy-server/monitor-squi-bandwidth-by-user-squidsquint/) (I haven't used Squint so dunno much about it).

Hope this helps...

Comment: Does any of those solutions allow me to inspect client information, such as browser version?

Comment: @vinnylinux - Do u want to restrict/enforce a particular type of browser on the user's end?

Comment: Yes, and also i'm interested in other specific header fields. Based on the info of those headers, i will either redirect the user, or send a blank response.